# Groovy script to convert UTC time to CEST (CET) time

Tags: groovy, timezone, utc, converters

I have a linux server and it is following a timezone of UTC, and for project related details I need to fetch some details using CEST time since all windows servers are maintaining in CEST.

I have tried some scripts using Groovy to convert UST to CEST and no luck still. Since I am new to Groovy, If someone used such groovy scripts can you put some sample scripts regarding the same ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Comment: date = new Date(initialDate).format('yyyyMMddHHmm', TimeZone.getTimeZone('CEST')) Used this line to convert from UTC to CEST. For example, current CEST time is 02.10 PM and UST time is 01.10 PM, after using the above script it provides output as 12.10 PM instead of 02.10. What change needs to resolve this ?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70435552/edit) the question. Comments are not suitable to paste code.

Comment: What was the answer for the now deleted https://stackoverflow.com/q/70750287/6309 ?

Comment: Update lscm command to 7.0.2 version

Comment: @Kivi OK. That would be helpful to keep the question up, and post an answer: that way, others with the same error message would have benefited from your experience.